# LocalBroadcastManager, redundant activities, Activity lifecycle

Tags: java, android

I have a big application, our first activity is MainActivity the second one is a LoginActivity (For multiple reason can be a Fragment or a DialogFragment)

The LoginActivity is initialized by MainActivity, in a normal flow, the application need to reload the header in a NavigationDrawer. 
I already have a function like this, in MainActivity.

```
private void loadUser () {
   //Reload header
}
```

Inside the LoginActivity I have a LocalBroadcastManager like the next one

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("RELOAD_MENU");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(c).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Inside MainActivity I have the receiver

```
 private BroadcastReceiver loginReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        loadUser();
    }
};
```

onPause and onResume on the MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(loginReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("RELOAD_MENU"));
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //LocalBroadcastManager onPause
    super.onPause();
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(loginReceiver);
}
```

I missing something?

There is a problem with Activity A initialize Activity B and then Activity B start a LocalBroadcast that the Activity A must heard?

I also make some test with onDestroy just for testing, Im not receiving the LocalBroadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're unregistering the receiver in `MainActivity`'s `onPause ()` method.

You probably want to register the receiver in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()`, otherwise when you call `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(c).sendBroadcast(intent);` in `LoginActivity`, there are no listeners registered with the `LocalBroadcastManager` because `MainActivity` is paused while `LoginActivity` is visible on the screen.